# Display event emitter value in html template with async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a child component that selects a file with a 2 way data binding called file$ so the parent can receive the selected file.

The parent needs to receive the file when it is emitted, but the child also needs to display the file name in the template.

For some reason the file name is not being displayed in the child's html template. Why is this? I have subscribed to the file$ event emitter and console logged the emitted value which is indeed a file.

in child component .ts:

```
@Output() public file$ = new EventEmitter<any>(true);

private setDocument(uploadedFile: File): void {
    if (this.isFilesizeValid && this.isFileExtensionValid) {
        this.file$.emit(uploadedFile);
        this.isFileValidAndUploaded = true;
    }
}
```

in child component .html:

`<h4 class="cb-padding-bottom">{{file$.name | async}}</h4>`

In parent file .html:

```
      <cb-drag-and-drop-file fxFlex
                             [allowedFileTypes]="[FILE_TYPE_ENUM.Xlsx]"
                             [(file$)]="file">
      </cb-drag-and-drop-file>
```

In parent file .ts:

```
public file;
```

Comment: Dubiousness of "2 way binding" on an output event aside... the async pipe should be applied to Observables, and you can access properties of the observed value like `{{ (file$ | async).name }}`

Answer (score 0):

`file$.name` itself is not an observable, so piping it through `async` will not work.

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
{{file$ | async}}?.name
```

The `?.` is needed because the async pipe returns `null` before the observable emits.

It is also worth mentioning that `EventEmitter` is an Angular concept and technically not guaranteed to always be implemented as an observable. [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29499#issuecomment-475999795)